# Is it bad practice to handle the showing of the open file dialog, and other dialogs, from within a custom textbox control?

Tags: mvvm, textbox, dialog, custom-controls

I am making a custom textbox control and am thinking about adding keybindings in the constructor that execute commands to open and save files. I am also thinking about handling the find and replace dialog from within my textbox control.

Is there a reason I shouldn't do this?

**--Edit--**

I am planning on only using this control in my current application. One of the reasons I am thinking of doing this is to avoid binding to the textbox's Text property, since this binding seems like it would be just as inefficient as updating a string on the textbox's textchanged event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, flexibility comes to mind.  Consider the following scenarios, which would be impossible (or at least difficult) in your control:

1. You want to handle multiple or different methods of opening a file, but it depends on your application.
2. You want to use your textbox but limit the functionality -- e.g., Find/Replace is not allowed.
3. You want to change the behavior of any of that in one application but not the other.  For example, in app A you want to tack on an extra slash to the end of the text, but in app B you want to add a custom folder name.

In general, I would consider something more generic.  Something like a textbox has a specific purpose; enhancing that purpose is fine, but you're going beyond that.  You're taking logic that rightly belongs to the app and putting it on a specific control.  That limits what you can do with the control across multiple apps.

Of course, if you're writing a control specifically for one and only one app, you don't need to worry about these things.  But I would still consider it a bad practice, myself.